# Github Actions Secrets value is blank after adding a new Secret

Tags: github, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, github-secret

- I'm using Github Actions workflow to deploy an Asp.Net Core MVC app to an Azure Web App Service.
- I have added the secret in the Github Actions Secrets section of the Github repository.
- When I click on the secret again to view the value, it shows nothing, and the field is completely blank.

[image]

Is this a bug in Github?

Comment: "Secret values are encrypted and cannot be displayed, but you can enter a new value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a feature - old value of the secret is not visible.

You can only enter new value.